# What is the process of repairing a corrupt OST file of Outlook 2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Recently, I upgrade my system to windows 10. As everyone knows that, while upgrading, some software or application were uninstalled. But in my case, Outlook doesn't recognise my ost file anymore after the upgrade.Then, I was setting account profile again in Outlook for recognition but it doesn't work.
I want to save OST file because there are so many important emails contain in it.
Guys, help out plz?

Comment: .OST files are just a cache of what is stored on the server.  They do not contain anything that isn't already on the server.  So your emails are not stored in this file, just setup a new connection to the email account, and you can view your important emails.  There isn't a process to fix your .OST since it actually isn't corrupt.

Comment: Then why isn't synchronize with my profile? I need complete solution of this problem, not a comment

Comment: There isn't a solution.  As I explained the file is just a cache of what is already on the server.  So just configure Outlook, to connect to the account, and it will be exactly how you left it.  There isn't anything to answer, the file you have, is invalid unless you restore the same Outlook profile which isn't possible.

Comment: Ok... fine! I will do that what have you said. But I need old emails in my new profile, then what 'll I do?

Comment: Your emails will be there since they are on the server.

Comment: @JoshiKhana You need to understand the manual methods to recover emails from a OST file. There are three manual methods: **Exporting**, **Archive**, and Creating a **New PST** file. By following few simple steps, you will be able to recover your data from the OST file without any software. Find the [manual methods](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Everything-You-Need-to-5d1f76c3) and try to recover your OST file. To go on  with exchange server, you need to create a new profile. Old OST file will not work.

Comment: @Kiname_Cole I will try your method, first of all!

Answer (score 0):

Just close Outlook and delete/rename old OST file. Then start Outlook and it will create OST again by retrieving all data from your account (IMAP/Office365/Exchange/...).

Or just create a new Outlook profile for your account.

Comment: Hi, Thims! I cannot get it. Can you elaborate your solution in details!!

Comment: What exactly can't you get? You can't delete OST or you can't create a new Outlook profile?

Comment: Yeah, I don't want delete! But Can I do like this! After creating a new Outlook profile,can OST  be imported to new Outlook profile? Or need a conversion for that as well?

Comment: You, you can't import OST. But why you even need it? This is just a local cache of your remote account.

Comment: You don't need to delete your OST file, just rename OST part to OLD. Anything in your OST is already on the Exchange Server so you will not lose anything.

Comment: Ok..I try to do that, and come to you

Answer (score 0):

Using scanpst.exe utility you can easily repair your corrupt OST file.
I tell you the entire process of scanpst.exe.
First, close to “Microsoft Outlook” before using Inbox Repair Tool.

Now follow these simple steps:

**Step1**: Double click on SCANOST.EXE.

**Step2**: If your Outlook application is running then it will ask you to close it.

**Step3**: Else, a new window open i.e OST Integrity Tool. If the tool asks for Profile name then provide the accurate name.

**Step4**: Now, if you will see a message Connect or Work Offline then click on Connect.

**Step5**: Select an option according to your priority either Scan all folders or Choose the folder to scan and click Begin Scan.

**Step6**: Once the scanning process completed you will receive a message OST repaired successfully.

I hope helps it

Thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

There are quite a few solutions with which you can repair your OST files.

One solution is to update your folder. You can right click on the folder and then properties. A dialog box appears and under this dialog box, click the clear offline items option. Then click OK. Now, on the outlook ribbon, go to the send/receive option and click update folder.

Another solution that you can use scanpst. You can run scanpst.exe and then it will check for errors and it would repair them. If the files can’t be repaired it will recreate it.

More info: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/937-repair-outlook-profiles-and-ost-pst-files

Comment: This solution isn’t applicable to the author’s question